# Can one specify different compiler options for different modules in the same IntelliJ IDEA project?

Tags: android, build, intellij-idea

We have an Android project with multiple modules. One of the modules is mostly code from a different team that doesn't care about things like deprecated APIs. Due to some business and process limitations we have to tweak their code from time to time and we build it in our main project. In eclipse, we have simply disabled most warnings for that part of the code (a project in eclipse, a module in intellij).

Can one do that in IntelliJ? Is it possible generally to set different compilation options for different modules? More specifically, is it possible to disable deprecation warnings for one module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do this exactly - or at least I haven't found a way either.

One option is to hide warnings when your rebuild your project and then use the inspector when you want to analyse your code for good coding standards.

To hide warnings: In the messages window there is a little button on the message window toolbar. Click this!

To Inspect your code, use Analyze/Inspect Code from the menu. This then allows you to include/exclude modules for inspection. There are lots of options in the preferences which control which how things get flagged by the inspector.

Comment: There is an exclude from validation option which can be accessed from compiler preferences. This allows you to exclude  folder(s)/file(s) from validation during project build. It doesn't seem to have the desired effect though - it seems to only work for the pre-defined validators.